# Working out top 5 places of residence from a normalised live/work relationship table

Tags: sql

I have a three column table and the column headers are: place of work, place of residence and number of commuters (geocode, geocode, number). For each place of work, I would like to know the top 5 most common places of residence along with the number of commuters. Any ideas on how to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which RDBMS you are using, but this should work with SQL Server:

```
with MyCTE AS
(
    select *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY placeOfWork ORDER BY NumberOfCommuters DESC) AS Rank
    from PlacesOfWorkWork
)
select * from MyCTE where Rank <= 5
```